# How to setup a dns for an ip address

Tags: dns, httpserver, nameservers

I setup up a HTTP server in home that is connected to the internet. I registered .COM a domain. Now I want to use this domain to connect to my server. but when i try to set my IP address as DNS I see this error :

```
Unable to update nameservers: Nameserver [MYIPADDRESS] doesn't exist at the registry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nameservers indicates what server owns the DNS records for the zone, you need to create A records, not update the Nameserver.  If you are on GoDaddy, switch to the "DNS Zone File" tab and then create an A record instead of trying to change the nameserver records.

Comment: i did it but after 10 hours nothing happened :(

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your TTL (Time To Live) value for the A-record. If the TTL is set to a higher time quanta, the changes will take a lot longer to propagate as the old IP address would still be cached.

Changing NS records would not be the ideal solution for what you are looking to accomplish as you are most likely not shunting traffic from one authoritative DNS server to another to answer queries for your zone.